# Tikz ER Diagram: Relationship between one entity

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

I'm drawing a simplified ER model with TikZ. This is the code so far:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside,openright]{report}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{er}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shapes,shadows,arrows}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[>=open triangle 90, thick,every node/.style={font=\footnotesize}, node distance = 6.2em]
node[entity] (page) {Page};
\node[relationship] (pageparent) [right of = page] {parent} edge node[above]{n...1} (page) edge (page);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

It creates an entity, a relationship object, and a straight edge between those two. I need a second edge between those two objects to complete the diagram, preferably in this way:

```
   |----------------------------|     
   |                            |
   |                            |
[ Page ] ----------------- < parent >
```

How can I add the second edge, with the two 90° angles?

Comment: First, you have missed \begin{document} in your MWE.  by adding just before `\end{tikzpicture}` the following code: `\coordinate[above= 1cm of page] (cpage);
\coordinate[above= 0.8cm of pageparent] (cpageparent);
\draw[-] (page)--(cpage)--(cpageparent)--(pageparent);`
Is that what you wanted?

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thank you! Feel free to post that as an answer as well, if you want to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by defining `coordinate`s as follows:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside,openright]{report}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{er}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shapes,shadows,arrows}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[>=open triangle 90, thick,every node/.style={font=\footnotesize}, node distance = 6.2em]
\node[entity](page){Page};
\node[relationship] (pageparent) [right of =page] {parent} edge node[above]{n...1} (page) edge (page);
\coordinate[above= 1cm of page] (cpage);
\coordinate[above= 0.8cm of pageparent] (cpageparent);
\draw[-] (page)--(cpage)--(cpageparent)--(pageparent);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```